# the first Jmeter assertion in my test expects extra characters I did not define. How to make my results accurate?

Tags: performance, jmeter, assertion

I am looping through a .csv file of inputs for a chat bot, and validating their responses using Response Assertion.

The first row gives me this message, and a failure

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to contain /The intent is 
ï»¿EntityWhat/
```

I don't know what is causing it to expect those extra characters. They are not in the response at all, or in my Assertion. The very next row passes the assertion. Both of the responses do contain the text `The intent is EntityWhat`

Has anyone else come across this weird glitch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV file contains [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which is not visible with the majority of text editors but not for JMeter. You need to replace/remove this character somehow